# Finding a formula in predicate logic for continuity and differentiation.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I need to solve the following:

> Let $f,g$ be binary function symbols, $P$ a binary predicate symbol, $c,d$ constant symbols and let $\mathcal{L} := \{f,g;P;c,d\}$.
>
> Consider $R :=< R; +, ·; <; 0, 1 >$ as an $\mathcal{L}$-structure. Let $h$ be a unary function symbol, let $\mathcal{L}′ := \mathcal{L}∪\{h\}$ and let $\mathcal{R}′$ be $\mathcal{R}$ together with an interpretation $h_{\mathcal{R}′}$ of $h$ in $\mathcal{R}$.
>   Find $\mathcal{L}′$-formulas $\phi$ and $\psi$ such that
>
> i) $\mathcal{R′} \vDash \phi$ iff $h_{\mathcal{R}′}$ is continuous.
>
> ii) $\mathcal{R′} \vDash \psi$ iff $h_{\mathcal{R}′}$ is differentiable.

I am reasonably unsure on where to start here. I need to basically figure out how to write the traditional $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall \epsilon > 0$   $\exists \delta >0$ such that for $y$ such that $|x-y|< \delta$, $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$, in the language above, but I don't quite know how to formulate it. If I was shown how to do the first, I think I could attempt the differentiability one myself. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Comment : the function in the "number-world" must be named $h$, while $f$ is the name in the language-world of sum.

Comment: We have no $-$ sign and thus we have to introduce it as an abbreviation; something like : $a-b=a+(-b)$. In turn, the additive inverse must be defined as $-a=(\iota z)(a+z=0)$ (the **unique** $z$ such that...). Do you think it may work ?

Comment: If so, the basic clause is : $|x−y|<δ \to |h(x)−h(y)|<ϵ$. We may  unpack the inequality as : $-δ < (x-y) \land (x-y) < δ$.